# Recurrent Neural Network - Fail to apply learning rate reduction

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, learning-rate

I am building a RNN model using Tensorflow Keras, and I want to reduce learning rate whenever an validation accuracy does not increase. However, I have received an error message indicating container does not exist. I have tried to explicitly initialize the learning rate; however, the same issue still happens. Does anyone who what is going on? Below are my code of my model and learning rate reduction function.

```
lr_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy',
                             patience=5, 
                             verbose=1, 
                             factor=0.5, 
                             min_lr=0.000001)

model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocal_size, embedding_dim, 

input_length=max_length),
                tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model_1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_1.summary()

epochs = 15
model_1_hist = model_1.fit(train_padded_sequence, train_target, epochs=epochs,
                          validation_data = (valid_padded_sequence, valid_target),
                           verbose=1,
                           callbacks=[lr_reduction]
                          )

Train on 6090 samples, validate on 1523 samples
Epoch 1/15
5888/6090 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5245 - acc: 0.7328
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1355     try:
-> 1356       return fn(*args)
   1357     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1340       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1341           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1342 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1428         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1429         run_metadata)
   1430 

FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable Adam_2/learning_rate from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/Adam_2/learning_rate)
     [[{{node Adam_2/learning_rate/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-212-62874f053345> in <module>
      3                           validation_data = (valid_padded_sequence, valid_target),
      4                            verbose=1,
----> 5                            callbacks=[lr_reduction]
      6                           )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    778           validation_steps=validation_steps,
    779           validation_freq=validation_freq,
--> 780           steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
    781 
    782   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    417     if mode == ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    418       # Epochs only apply to `fit`.
--> 419       callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    420     progbar.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    421 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    309     logs = logs or {}
    310     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 311       callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    312 
    313   def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
   1371     def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
   1372         logs = logs or {}
-> 1373         logs['lr'] = K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)
   1374         current = logs.get(self.monitor)
   1375         if current is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_value(x)
   2667         A Numpy array.
   2668     """
-> 2669     return x.eval(session=get_session())
   2670 
   2671 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in eval(self, session)
    898     if context.executing_eagerly():
    899       raise RuntimeError("Trying to eval in EAGER mode")
--> 900     return self._graph_element.eval(session=session)
    901 
    902   def numpy(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    729 
    730     """
--> 731     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    732 
    733 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   5577                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
   5578                        "graph.")
-> 5579   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
   5580 
   5581 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    948     try:
    949       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 950                          run_metadata_ptr)
    951       if run_metadata:
    952         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1171     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1172       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1173                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1174     else:
   1175       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1348     if handle is None:
   1349       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1350                            run_metadata)
   1351     else:
   1352       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1368           pass
   1369       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1370       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1371 
   1372   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable Adam_2/learning_rate from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/Adam_2/learning_rate)
     [[node Adam_2/learning_rate/Read/ReadVariableOp (defined at <ipython-input-212-62874f053345>:5) ]]

Original stack trace for 'Adam_2/learning_rate/Read/ReadVariableOp':
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 563, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 148, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 534, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1771, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 690, in <lambda>
    lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 787, in inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 748, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 272, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 542, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 294, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2855, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3058, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-212-62874f053345>", line 5, in <module>
    callbacks=[lr_reduction]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 780, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 157, in model_iteration
    f = _make_execution_function(model, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 532, in _make_execution_function
    return model._make_execution_function(mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2276, in _make_execution_function
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2219, in _make_train_function
    params=self._collected_trainable_weights, loss=self.total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 497, in get_updates
    return [self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 434, in apply_gradients
    self._create_hypers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 608, in _create_hypers
    aggregation=tf_variables.VariableAggregation.ONLY_FIRST_REPLICA)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 770, in add_weight
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 663, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 155, in make_variable
    shape=variable_shape if variable_shape.rank else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 259, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 220, in _variable_v1_call
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 198, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2495, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 263, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 460, in __init__
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 649, in _init_from_args
    value = self._read_variable_op()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 935, in _read_variable_op
    self._dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py", line 587, in read_variable_op
    "ReadVariableOp", resource=resource, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Answer (score 0):

did you import Adam as in

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Comment: Yes, "Adam" was imported. Even I have explicitly initialized a learning rate, i still receives an error message.

Comment: Hmm give the code a run but don't use the callback. See if the error still happens